# Dropdown menu populated from sql with url redirect

Tags: mysql

For the three dropdown menu I have the sql table as follows:

[sql city table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufsl7.png)

I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#city_id").change(function(){ 
window.location=$("#city_url");
});
```

How do I acomplish my goal so when the city is selected it redirects to the corresponding url?

Comment: What is you code where you fetch your SQL database to create your listbox ?

Comment: $.post( "dropdown3ck.php", {"state_id":$('#state_id').val()},function(return_data,status){
$("#city_id").append("<option value=''>Select City</option>");
$.each(return_data.city, function(key,value){
$("#city_id").append("<option value=" + value.city_id +">"+value.city+"</option>");
});
},"json");

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your URL in your option.
It shoudl work if you put the url in the value but I suggest you to use a data-attributes

```
$("#city_id").append("<option data-url=\""+ value.city_url+"\" value=" + value.city_id +">"+value.city+"</option>");
```

it should render you something like

`<option data-url="http://miami.com" value=1>Miami</option>`

Then you can redirect to this attribute (according your `select` has a id="city_id")

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#city_id").change(function(){ 
window.location=$(this).data("url");
});
```

Code is not tested but you should understand the way to do it

Comment: Post the output of your select. Not how you build it but really the generated HTML

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /test/test/undefined was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: that's not what I asked

Comment: That's all I get. Not Found page.

Comment: "Post the output of your select. Not how you build it but really the generated HTML" Where is your html code ? <select><option>Miami</option>......

Comment: <select style="width:216px;" id=city_id name=city_id><option value=''>Select City</option></select>

Comment: nothing work, don't you see that city_id is not replaced ? id and name are not surrounded by double quotes ? and you have no options. So your question was bad, you don't know how to build a select in fact so why are you asking for a redirection ? Waste of time

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: <select style="width:216px;" id="city_id" name="city_id"><option value=''>Select City</option></select>